# DataReader Erro Dados são Null

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Boa noite!

estou com impasse em trazer dados de um DataReader com valores Null. Ele simplesmente não deixa trazer os resultados.

Queria que viesse mesmo contendo valores null, para usuários poderem atualizar no banco através do forms

erro que aparece:
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Dados são Null. Não é possível chamar este método ou esta propriedade em valores Null.'

```
SqlConnection con = ConectDAO.abrir();
                        SqlCommand conexao = new SqlCommand("SEARCH_DADOS_INFO_PREST_TEXTBOX", con);
                        conexao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CNPJ", SqlDbType.Int);
                        conexao.Parameters["@CNPJ"].Value = toolStripTXT_Pesq_Cnpj.Text;
                        conexao.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlDataReader dr;
                        dr = conexao.ExecuteReader();
                        dr.Read();
                       //txt_CODPASTA.Text = dr.GetString(0);
                       txt_razao.Text = dr.GetString(1);
                       txt_nomeFant.Text = dr.GetString(2);
                       txt_CNPJgroup.Text = dr.GetString(3);
                       txt_cep.Text = dr.GetString(4);
                       txt_end.Text = dr.GetString(5);
                       txt_Compl.Text = dr.GetString(6);
                       txt_Num.Text = dr.GetString(7);
                       txt_Bair.Text = dr.GetString(8);
                       txt_Cid.Text = dr.GetString(9);
                       txt_UF.Text = dr.GetString(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque os retornos do `DataReader` não são dos mesmos tipos do `.NET`, então quando executa um `GetString` ou outro tipo qualquer (`GetInt` por exemplo), o valor é convertido, e um valor `null` vai dar erro.

Neste caso basta verificar se o valor é `DBNull` antes:

```
txt_razao.Text = dr.IsDBNull(1) ? null : dr.GetString(1);
```

Ou seja, valida primeiro se é `DBNull` (tipo nulo que vem do banco de dados), se for, deixa o valor como `null`, senão lê o valor com `GetString`

Comment: deu certo! poderia me explicar um pouco mais sobre o IsDBNull(1) ? null e porque é usado ? e null diante um tratamento isdbnull, já nao bastaria? abraços

Comment: quanto o DataReader retorna os dados eles não são os mesmos do .NET, por exemplo não tem um `string`, tem um `varchar`, e por ai vai.. da mesma forma, o null do banco para o DataReader é um `DBNull`, então o `IsDBNull(1)` verifica se a coluna de índice 1 do seu reader é null.
Aproveitando, evite usar os índices, se os campos mudam de ordem na query ou procedure vai dar erro, prefira `GetString("nome do campo")`